# How can I be notified whenever a new site leaves Area 51?

Tags: support, area-51

Can I be notified whenever a new site leaves Area 51?

If so, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are committed to the proposal, you'll get an email.

Alternatively, you can follow the [beta feeds](http://area51.stackexchange.com/?tab=beta).

Comment: Will this notify me whenever a site enters beta from Area 51 *as well as* when it leaves beta to become a full site? These two use cases are what I'd like to be notified about. I notice that there is both a "beta" and a "launched" feed on Area 51.

Comment: @LoverofStructure The launched feed will tell you when the site graduated to a full site.